# Private sub change not seeing value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` event. The range `E4` is a data validation list with 5 string items. For the first four, I want to input the formula in the range `F4:Z4`. For the fifth item, I want the range `F4:Z4` to be empty. I keep getting a Type mismatch error with the first `IF` line. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Range
Set x = Range("E4")

If x.Value = "Standard 2020 CAD" Or "Standard 2020 USD" Or "Standard 2020 Pipeline CAD" Or "Standard 2020 Pipeline USD" Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(x, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F4:Z4").Formula = "=INDEX($XBR$4:$XBU$24,MATCH(F3,$XBQ$4:$XBQ24,0),MATCH($E$4,$XBR$3:$XBU$3,0))"
    End If
Else
    If Not Application.Intersect(x, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F4:Z4").Value = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

As an aside, I would also like to have the range `F4:Z4` locked if it contains the formulas (ie. one of the first four list items) and unlocked if it is blank.

Comment: Use `Select Case` here.

Comment: You'd need to write `If x=a or x=b` etc but I'd agree with BigBen.

Comment: @SJR @BigBen Thanks both. I tried and tried and tried with `Select Case` and could not get it to work. I gave up and just used the solution provided by @SJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Select Case` would be like so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Range
Set x = Range("E4")

If Not Application.Intersect(x, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case x.Value
        Case "Standard 2020 CAD", "Standard 2020 USD", "Standard 2020 Pipeline CAD", "Standard 2020 Pipeline USD"
            Range("F4:Z4").Formula = "=INDEX($XBR$4:$XBU$24,MATCH(F3,$XBQ$4:$XBQ24,0),MATCH($E$4,$XBR$3:$XBU$3,0))"
        Case Else
            Range("F4:Z4").ClearContents
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will continue learning and putting these into practice.